# Node edit form in overlay for selected content types

Tags: nodes, forms, modal-dialogs

I am using Drupal's core Overlay module along with [Overlay Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/overlay_paths) to display certain forms in overlay pop up. I have three content types and for one content type I want the node edit form to appear in overlay. If I override path by calling hook_overlay_paths_alter() then it adds overlay to all edit pages. How to I get overlay on only edit form of one node type?

Comment: I highly doubt if you can have different content types with separate edit paths.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1712414 issue will give you more details and workarounds..

Comment: Thank you Anil, the reference was good but after much research and trial I agree with Molot. It is difficult to have different paths for node edit forms of different content types.